SSH Permission Denied (public key) raspberry pi 4
I am trying to install Anthias on a Raspberry Pi 4. The operating system is Raspberry PI OS Legacy 64bit bullseye lite. When SSHing to connect to the Raspberry Pi, I am getting the permission denied (public key) error. I can't find a folder on the SD card to check the key.
Here is a picture of what I am getting -

Key was mage in imager software -


It is a PI problem. I can't connect to my Raspberry Pi to install Anthias because the keys aren't working. If you are unknowledgeable on the subject, why comment?

I can't find a folder on the SD card to check the key - how did you put the key on the raspberry pi in the first place? How did you disable SSH password authentication? You must have logged in to the pi at least once before to do that

This was done through the Raspberry Pi imager.

Oh, right, so you put the public key of a key pair you generated into the raspberry pi imager, and you have the corresponding private key in your .ssh folder. What type of keypair did you create?

Hi. I just used the imager. I've updated the original message

Currently there is not enough information here to demonstrate that it is really a Pi issue (eg., the imager is not adding the key or something).  If I had to guess, I'd say the key is not being applied on the laptop side.  Using -v or -vv as per Waxrat's answer should clear that up. "I can't find a folder on the SD card to check the key." For user pi it will be /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys.  However, I notice the imager refers to setting the key for 'admin'.  I've never used the imager but you should investigate that (is there a /home/admin on the card?).

The password was set-up for userid=admin, the ssh command is for userid=pi. Try fixing that with ssh admin@10.1.36.92.

There's probably something interesting in the logs on that host 10.1.36.92.
Only the very last line "Permission denied (public key)" is relevant.
You can also try ssh -v pi@10.1.36.92 to see more about what ssh is doing.
Most likely your ssh client is simply trying to authenticate in a way that the ssh server is rejecting.
